# Error installing Tensorflow 2 on Windows 11: SSL Decryption Failed or Bad Record Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

So I am having trouble installing Tensorflow on Windows 11. I'm using Anaconda with Python 3.7.0 and I'm trying to install Tensorflow 2.1.0. The problem I have is when I try to install tensorflow with conda install tensorflow or pip3 install tensorflow I get the following error every time after a few dependencies are installed:

[image]

The only thing I can think of is the internet connection is slow on my laptop, which has been the case ever since I upgraded to Windows 11. Is there anything I can do? When I tried to install an earlier version of Tensorflow (1.13.1) I finally got it to install after it got stuck on the MKL package. I just kept trying to install MKL individually until it installed. But when I try to upgrade to 2.1.0 I immediately get the above error before any dependencies are installed. Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I  have the same issue  while trying to update conda using :

> conda update conda

I notice the difference after my organisation updated the firewa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb9vz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set SSL verification off then update

```
set SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
```

Comment: That didn't work. Still getting the same error.